# Best JUNG Graph for Modeling Routes on an ESB

Tags: java, graph, apache-camel, jung

I'm a Java developer that is trying to model the Endpoints and Routes on my Camel-driven backend (SOA) as a graph of vertices and edges.

For instance, if I have a Camel route that starts with an ActiveMQ queue, dequeues its messages and passes them to a JavaBean, and then passes them to, say, a web service endpoint where the message is ultimately consumed into a database, then we have a route of three connected endpoints ("vertices"):

- ActiveMQ queue
- JavaBean
- Web Service

Moreover, two individual routes ("edges") connect these vertices (queue -> bean and bean -> web service).

Looking in JUNG2's `edu.uci.ics.jung.graph` package, we see *a lot* of graph types:

- AbstractGraph
- AbstractTypedGraph
- DelegateForest
- DelegateTree
- DirectedOrderedSparseMultigraph
- DirectedSparseGraph
- DirectedSparseMultigraph
- GraphDecorator
- ObservableGraph
- OrderedKAryTree
- OrderedSparseMultigraph
- SetHypergraph
- SortedSparseMultigraph
- SparseGraph
- SparseMultigraph
- UndirectedOrderedSparseMultigraph
- UndirectedSparseGraph
- UndirectedSparseMultigraph

If anybody out there is well-versed in JUNG2 (and/or graph structures in general), is there a "clear winner" on this list for how to represent Camel Endpoints/Routes as a graph?

The javadocs are pretty vague, and looking these objects up on Google/Wikipedia just churns up a lot of hardcore graph theory that I don't fully understand.

Comment: What is your ultimate aim?  Do you want to create a visualization of the relations, i.e., a diagram?  Or do you want the graph model for some other purpose?  It may be that JUNG is not the best tool for your purpose.

Comment: Not visualization - I'm actually trying to build my own "SOA framework" where I can define `my own `Endpoint` implementations (`CXFWebServiceEndpoint`, `ActiveMQTopicEndpoint`, etc.) and build my own routes. Under the hood I will be simply converting the vertices (`Endpoint` impls) and edges (routes) to Camel components and routes. But to store the "service bus" I figure a graph is the best data structure.

Comment: Just need something that extends `Graph<V,E>` and doesn't have unnecessary overhead, like `UndirectedSparseMultigraph`, etc.

Comment: In before "*why would you do that?!?!*" I can understand many out there might not agree or understand why I'm doing this, but I would just ask that you take the mentality "can't fix stupid" and let me wander down the wrong path if it is indeed the wrong path!! I just need to know which JUNG2 graph structure to use, or if JUNG2 isn't the right choice, perhaps a solid suggestion to point me in the right direction.

Comment: If you are trying to build your own framework, why not look at the Camel DSL? Doesn't that let you express your ideas clearly enough? If its _that_ complicated to use JUNG2 (and the docs aren't clear) it suggests its the wrong tool.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really described your requirements except possibly for someone who knows Camel (I don't).  However, it sounds like you have directed relationships, so you will want a DirectedGraph.  It also sounds like you have different classes of relationships.  It's not clear to me whether you will want all the classes of relationships represented in a single graph, or in multiple graphs; I also don't know whether two vertices can be connected by more than one edge (if so, you will need a Multigraph).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to model service hops with a graph, and roll your own execution engine on top of it.  This could have advantages over existing ESBs in that (a) design of service orchestration is more natural, and (b) runtime performance efficiencies will be realized for a large number of complex orchestrations.

For something like this, a directed graph should suffice, at least until you have a use case for something more complicated.  Ordering and sorting won't be very useful, especially if your orchestration is dynamic.

Curious how you proceeded on this...